# Different positions after scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I use script to scroll smoothly to form but every time I click button it scrolls to different positions. What should I do to make it stops every time at the same level. Like for example 100px above 'textarea'.

```
jQuery('.scroll-to-form').on('click', function() {
       jQuery('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: 
         jQuery('textarea').offset().top
       }, 1500, function() {
        jQuery('textarea').focus();
       });
     });
```

Comment: instead of jquery can you use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView ?

Comment: I'd rather use jQuery. I've tried to modify it a little and write                     
    jQuery('.scroll-to-form').on('click', function() {                                                      
       let bottom = jQuery(document).height() - jQuery(window).height()
       jQuery('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: 
         bottom-100
       }, 1500, function() {
        jQuery('textarea').focus();
       });
     });    
which suppose to scroll all the way down but apparently this one doesn't work either.